# AndroidHttpClient.execute is returning httpresponse as null

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask

I am trying to access my uri from the below code

```
    AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
            HttpUriRequest uriGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/restsql-0.8.6/res/");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(uriGetRequest);
                ;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                if(e!=null){
                Log.e("ModelLoader", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                Log.e("Model Loader", "Error while calling execute");
            }
            return httpResponse;
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute(new Object());
```

But always the httpresponse is null. Even no exception is thrown.
I have checked with a valid uri like https://google.co.in/ and its working fine.
Also my URI from browser is working fine .
As there is no exception thrown I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: Btw, if you don't need any parameters you can extend your AsyncTask with Void, like `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In AVD to connect to localhost you need to use url

```
       http://10.0.2.2/
```

instead of

```
        http://localhost/
```

For [reference](http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/08/cosume-phppost-method-webservice-in.html).

Comment: +1, `localhost` on your development machine corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface. If you want to access services running on your development machine's loopback interface, you should use the special address `10.0.2.2` instead

Comment: Why it shows me 400: Bad request... my services running on localhost. and I am calling it from android emulator with path : http://10.0.2.2:52511/api/Values/GetProduct/5

Answer (score 0):

To access `localhost` in emulator use `10.0.2.2`

```
http://localhost:8080/restsql-0.8.6/res/
```

should be

```
http://10.0.2.2:8080/restsql-0.8.6/res/
```

Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)